# Insert and updation of table

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have a table in which datas are given as follows

```
  SkillId     SkillName   Experience    KnowledgeLevelXId
    6            c++          NULL             NULL
    7          Asp.net        NULL             NULL
    9            Flex         NULL             NULL
    10      Flash builder     NULL             NULL
```

I wrote a Sp for insertion

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SkillSettingSave] 
(
     @SkillName varchar(100)
)   
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [HRM_SkillSetting]
        (
         [SkillName]
        )
    VALUES
        (
         @SkillName 
        )
```

I need to add update query in above sp, where skillname should not be repeated.

Comment: What should happen if it exists?

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to write an `IF EXISTS` conditional in your stored procedure.  This should be helpful: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/miah/archive/2008/02/17/sql-if-exists-update-else-insert.aspx

Comment: Sorry @David I can't understand

Comment: please any one help me to solve this

Comment: @Ramdas: In that case I highly recommend taking some time to learn some SQL before writing stored procedures.  What that article is demonstrating is basically how you can check if a record exists and, based on the results of that check, either update the record (if it does exist) or insert a new one (if it doesn't exist).  Unless I've completely misunderstood the question, in which case you should clarify.

Answer (score 0):

You might check for existance of a record using [exists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx). To avoid race condition you would do it in a single statement:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SkillSettingSave] 
(
     @SkillName varchar(100)
)
AS
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO [HRM_SkillSetting]
        (
         [SkillName]
        )
    -- Instead of using values you might use select
    SELECT @SkillName 
    -- And insert row only if it does not exists
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                         FROM [HRM_SkillSetting]
                        WHERE SkillName = @SkillName
                      )
END
```